# Simple regex trying to extract 3 or 4 numbers from "dirty" time string

Tags: php, regex

Despite some help earlier on I am still floundering in regex problems and now in array problems.

I am trying to allow users to put time in as 205pm 1405 14:05 2.05 pm and so on.

Previously I had times stored as 14:05 (standard mySQL TIME format) but users were not liking that but if I convert to 2:05 pm then, when the updated values are entered (in similar format), that obviously breaks the database.

I have NO TROUBLE going 14:05 to 2:05 pm but I am having a nightmare going in the opposite direction.

I have fudged things a bit with a cascading IF statement to get the string length but I have spent literally hours trying to get at the output.

IE if I get 2-05 pm, to start off with I just want to get 205.

Here is my atrocious code:

```
if ($_POST['xxx']='yyy')
{
    $stuff=$_POST['stuff'];

    $regex='/^\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*$/';
    if (preg_match($regex, $stuff, $matches)) {echo "  More than 4 digits. This cannot be a time."; }
else{
    $regex='/^\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*$/';
    if (preg_match($regex, $stuff, $matches)) {echo "  >>4 digits";}
else{
    $regex='/^\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*$/';
    if (preg_match($regex, $stuff, $matches)) {echo "  >>3 digits";}
 else{
    $regex='/^\d\D*\d\D*$/';
    if (preg_match($regex, $stuff, $matches)) {echo "  Less than 3 digits. This cannot be a time.";}
}
}
}
}
debug ($matches,"mat1");
$NEWmatches = implode($matches); 
debug ($matches,"matN1");
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $NEWmatches, $matches);
debug ($matches,"mat2");
$matches = implode($matches); 

debug ($matches,"mat3");
echo "<br> Matches $matches"; /// I hoped to get the digits only here
?>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Perhaps seeing actual input examples would be helpful.

Comment: Ok well I am trying anything with digits and non digits. Eg  55gg55 or a44h4 or 5.55 or12:44 or even a1b11c1d111 whatever. Now everything is broken. BTW debug is just a tiny little function to give clean `print_r` output. From 4:22 I just want to get a string of "412".

Answer (score 1):

```
$times = array(
 '205pm', '1405', '4:05', '2.05 pm'
);

foreach($times as $time)
{
   // parsing string into array with 'h' - hour, 'm' - minutes and 'ap' keys
   preg_match('/(?P<h>\d{1,2})\D?(?P<m>\d{2})\s*(?P<ap>(a|p)m)?/i', $time, $matches);

   // construction below is not necessary, it just removes extra values from array
   $matches = array_intersect_key($matches,
              array_flip(array_filter(array_keys($matches), 'is_string')));

   // output the result
   var_dump($matches);
}
```

If you are using that string at `strtotime` then it is easier just to reformat it to the correct format, like this

```
$times = array(
 '205pm', '1405', '4:05', '2.05 pm'
);

var_dump(preg_replace('/(\d{1,2})\D?(\d{2})(\s*(a|p)m)?/i', '$1:$2$3', $times));
```

ps: for more complex possible situations I would suggest to reformat the time and do something like this, otherwise regexp can be a nightmare..

```
$times = array(
 '9 pm', '205pm', '1405', '4:05', '2.05 pm'
);

$times = preg_replace('/(\d{1,2})\D?(\d{2})(\s*(a|p)m)?/i', '$1:$2$3', $times);

foreach($times as $time)
{
  $date = strtotime($time);
  if ($date === false) { echo 'Unable to parse the time ' . $time . "\n"; continue; }
  $hour = date('G', $date);
  $minutes = date('i', $date);
  echo $hour . " : " . $minutes . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Cheery thanks a million. That works like a charm. I am just trying to get a simple test site up and working. I will not be using strtotime for now. I do have one extra ask. Is it possible to interpret 1 pm 9 am 11pm WITHOUT breaking your wonderful regex? It sooooooo doesn’t matter if it is problematic and/or you do not have the time. Your code has sorted put a stupid problem I made for myself. The lesson being – I suspect – if it ain’t broke don’t fix it. Once again big thanks.

Comment: is it possible to just pass any (alphabetical) characters through then I can do a simple check and if someone has accidentally typed "om" instead of "pm" then I can catch it. Currently, if there is an a or p in the first place or m in  last place then it will be interpreted as "am" (ax, px, xp are all interpreted as am) - a bit nervous as this is for an automated SMS system. I am going to put an "are you sure" for any texts before 7 am but would like to catch errors more aggressively. I must stop thinking about this this is a tweak while other big things need doing!

Comment: @BeNice look at update. `is it possible to just pass any (alphabetical) characters through then` yes, replace `(a|p)m` with what you want, but `strtotime` will not recognize it and you can check whether it returns `false`

Comment: Cheery -sorted! `(?P<h>\d{1,2})\D?\D?(?P<m>\d{2})\s*(?P<ap>([a-z])[a-z])?`. I want to allow people to put in a time "naturally (I only need a time). This allows me to capture the individual components and then work on them individually. strtotime is great for more complex tasks but this is very simple and, with a couple of methods, I cam make sure that mistakes are caught 99% of the time. Thank you SO much. Unbelievably helpful. BTW [regex101](http://regex101.com) was incredibly helpful for me to begin to understand what was going on. Recommended for other newbs. Aloha and mahalo nui loa.

Comment: `\D?\D?` can be just replaced by `\D*`

Answer (score 0):

For your given example "2-05 or 14:05" you can use this RegEx:

```
^(?<HOUR>[0-9]{1,2})\s{0,}((-|:|\.)\s{0,})?(?<MIN>[0-9]{2})\s{0,}(?<MODE>(a|p)m)?$
```

"Hour" will hold the the first 2 numbers of the string, "MIN" will always hold the last 2 numbers of the string. "MODE" will hold (am or pm)

So you can combine them at the end to an single string. Also you can just run an simple `Replace("-","")`.

Comment: I am late running out for a friend's birthday thing but if that works I owe you big time. More later. Vielen dank. Steve

Comment: Thanks for the input. I needed am/pm too (building this for an American audience). Thanks for taking the time to help.